# How to fix error of google play service version error on xamarin forms android?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-play-services

I'm working on a xamarin forms project. On building the android project this error happens and prevents building:

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')
```

The installed android sdk is 8.1. Also I installed the google play service item from extra services node on sdk manager. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: remove bin and obj, delete the `ResourceDesigner.cs` file clean build the project, include the auto-generated `ResourceDesginer.cs` and the issue should get solved

Comment: I did what you said but the issue still exists. @G.hakim

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT That did not helped. The problem still exits.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps on android. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Check your sdk manager and see if theres an update. And try updating it

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the packages from share folder and Obj Folder in Project, then Clean -> Build the project Path to share folder :

C:/Users/user/AppData\Local\Xamarin Obj Folder in Project : .Droid\obj\Debug

Under these paths, delete all the packages you can see, then clean and make a build. This build might take some time to build.